# Difference between "папа" and "отец"?

Tags: словоупотребление, выбор-слова

In Russian is there a difference between папа and отец? If there is, is it like Dad vs Daddy in English?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> In Russian is there a difference between папа and отец? If there is,
>   is it like Dad vs Daddy in English?

Yes, there is, and no, it is not like Dad vs Daddy. ''Отец'' is a formal, official word and is like ''father.'' ''Папа'' is how children actually address their father at home and is like ''dad.'' ''Daddy'' is ''папочка,'' ''папусик,'' ''папуля,'' etc.

Answer (score 11):

It is like dad and father.

Daddy is папочка.

Comment: This is the correct answer, Elena is right

Answer (score -3):

Отец - officially, Папа - tender value

Comment: Hi and welcome to Russian.SE! Thank you for your contribution effort. I just wanted to tell that on this site we try to avoid having lots of similar answers to the same question. Instead of posting another answer which adds nothing to the existing ones, please consider upvoting on of them once you have enough reputation to do that. Thank you!